# Did you know we're hosting a week-long giveaway?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So, as part of my ongoing site promotion prime directive, we're hosting a week-long giveaway over at [Make a House a Home](http://joeyandlana.com). Five days, five items, and lots of awesomeness in general! We picked the items jointly; our community picked/gave feedback on the options and Lana and I chose items that fit both of our goals. They were a pleasure to work with, and I really like their blog, as well. (Hence, well, why we're doing a giveaway with them.)

Our [first giveaway](http://joeyandlana.com/joey-and-lana-home/2011/9/26/lets-talk-dirty-giveaway.html) entry went live this morning. It looks pretty cool, in my opinion!

[image: the entry itself]

If you want to enter, follow the directions in the entry itself. The giveaway entry form is lower on the page:

[image: where to enter]

[EDIT!] Here's [round two](http://joeyandlana.com/joey-and-lana-home/2011/9/27/to-paint-is-to-diy-giveaway.html)!

Comment: Just curious, where the winners ever announced for this?

Comment: They were and I AM SO BAD ABOUT FOLLOWING UP LATELY. D: D: They won AGES ago and I've been redonk busy getting other things together. I will update this post by the end of the week. Slash, hopefully get these kind people their things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew, but only because I saw you mention it on the chat section.  Is there anyway to promote the giveaway on the main Q&A side of DIY.SE?

Comment: The question is being promoted in the meta sidebar section on the mainsite:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vsYlF.png